# any image breaks ajax on delete link

Tags: ajax, font-awesome, buddypress

Using BuddyPress 2.0, WP 3.9.1

I can replace the activity stream item `Delete` text with a Font Awesome icon, but when clicked it causes a page reload instead of using ajax.

Replacing the text with a basic img tag has the same effect, so I don't think it's specific to font awesome.

Any ideas as to why or a solution?

```
function sc_swap_delete_text( $link ) {
    $trash = '<i class="icon-trash icon-large"></i>';       
    $link = str_replace("Delete", $trash, $link);       
    return $link;
}
add_filter( 'bp_get_activity_delete_link', 'sc_swap_delete_text', 1, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the jquery in global.js

The 'target' becomes the icon rather than the a tag.
So `if ( target.hasClass('delete-activity')` fails.

Solution if, for example you're using the trash icon from font-awesome:
Changing to this gets the right target: `if ( target.hasClass('icon-trash')`

And then you need to change: `var link_href = target.attr('href');`

to: `var link_href = target.closest("a").attr("href");`

otherwise the nonce won't be found and the ajax will fail.

Note: why is global.js being loaded from BuddyPress Default Theme when BP Legacy Theme is being used?  Don't know, but something is funky in this particular installation.